# when is RT_PREEMPT patch released for Linux kernel 4.11

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, real-time, preemption, preempt-rt

When is RT_PREEMPT patch released for linux kernel 4.11, the newest stable Linux Kernel?

I know I can enable CONFIG_PREEMPT in the mainline Linux Kernel but what are the differences between this mainline PREEMPT and the RT_PREEMPT patch?
 Does the latter do a better job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does better job.

The release date and version is subject to define by working group. Most likely next one will be v4.14 or alike, so called LTS (long term support) version of Linux kernel. Latest available for now is v4.9 or v4.4 -- both are LTS.

More details are provided on the [RT Wiki](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/start).

Comment: Should the version of the patch correspond to that of the kernel, e.g., patch 4.4.60 should only be used on Linux kernel 4.4.60? If that is true, then only a few of patches are available and restrict people's choice of the kernel version.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Though it looks like you missed the page on that Wiki that describes development process, in particular it refers to the repository where other versions are tagged. So, I see v4.4.59 based kernel there and so on.